# Resampling multiindex dataframe with one of the index containing string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df:

             ticker       A        B        C           D 
Date         symbol
2022-01-01      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
2022-01-02      EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-07      MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-12      XYZ       1        0        0           0
```

I want to resample the dataframe on a daily basis (for the Date index) and I want to carry over the values for the symbol index to all dates (i.e. forward fill the symbol index and the values for the columns as well).

So my final dataframe should look like this

```
df_final:

             ticker       A        B        C           D 
Date         symbol
2022-01-01      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
2022-01-02      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-03      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-04      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-05      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-06      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
2022-01-07      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-08      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-09      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-10      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-11      XYZ       0        1        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
2022-01-12      XYZ       1        0        0           0
                JFK     0.5        0      0.5           0
                EFG       0        0        1           0
                MNO       0      0.5      0.5           0
```

There was a post about this ([Resampling a pandas MultiIndex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556620/resampling-a-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)) but I could not get it to work.

How can this be done?

Comment: unstack the `symbol` level, resample as normal, and stack `symbol` back.